# How close could a traversable wormhole be to Earth?

Tags: wormholes

How far outside of the solar system would it need to be to not have any negatives effects on the planets within? The wormhole has to be large enough to fit say an aircraft carrier though it.

Could you put it in the Kuiper belt or the Oort cloud?

Comment: Depending on the nature of exotic matter, there is a possibility that the wormhole could be planted right on the surface of the planet. Given many theoretical models of wormholes suggest they are very unstable,you might need to place the wormhole far out in space to avoid may disturbances. The real answer might be somewhere in between.

Comment: Do you mean an Einstein-Rosen bridge? Or those stupid magical teleportation gateways in science fiction?

Comment: Unless you want the answer to simply be some variation of "whatever sounds good" you may want a hard-science tag on this question.

Comment: “whatever sounds go9d for the plot”.  Does it need to be far away and you want a giod *reason* for that? Or do you want to put it in the middle of a military base and want to make sure that's plausible?  You didn't use any tqgs to indicate, and there is no real way to tell in your universe.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the nature of the wormhole. Recently Thorne-Morris wormholes have been very fashionable. They do need exotic matter to stay open because they are extremely unstable.

However, there is a better alternative. A wormhole that doesn't need exotic matter to stay open. This is the [Ellis wormhole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole). Just read down to the section on Traversable Wormholes for more details.

> The possibility of traversable wormholes in general relativity was first demonstrated in a 1973 paper by Homer Ellis[18] and independently in a 1973 paper by K. A. Bronnikov.[19] Ellis thoroughly analyzed the topology and the geodesics of the Ellis drainhole, showing it to be geodesically complete, horizonless, singularity-free, and fully traversable in both directions.

There are other possible configurations of wormholes that could also be considered as fit for purpose.

> Kip Thorne and his graduate student Mike Morris, unaware of the 1973 papers by Ellis and Bronnikov, manufactured, and in 1988 published, a duplicate of the Ellis wormhole for use as a tool for teaching general relativity. For this reason, the type of traversable wormhole they proposed, held open by a spherical shell of exotic matter, was from 1988 to 2015 exclusively referred to in the literature as a Morris–Thorne wormhole. Later, other types of traversable wormholes were discovered as allowable solutions to the equations of general relativity, including a variety analyzed in a 1989 paper by Matt Visser, in which a path through the wormhole can be made where the traversing path does not pass through a region of exotic matter. However, in the pure Gauss–Bonnet gravity (a modification to general relativity involving extra spatial dimensions which is sometimes studied in the context of brane cosmology) exotic matter is not needed in order for wormholes to exist—they can exist even with no matter.

Essentially what this comes to down is if you a suitable model for a wormhole you can put it effectively whether you want to, within the bounds of ordinary safety. For example, Thorne-Morris wormholes do have this bad habit of collapsing. If this involves the neighbourhood sprayed with exotic matter this might be quite hazardous to health. In which case, they should be located a long way away. Somewhere beyond the orbit of the planet Pluto sounds safe enough. Whereas Ellis wormholes could be located anywhere safely. There will be a few safeguards that will be necessary. Don't leave them too open because velocity differences between the two mouths will create hurricane force winds. An airlock would fix this problem.

If your wormhole can be located on the surface of Earth it will make the problem sending an aircraft carrier through it so much easier.

Answer (score 2):

I think this depends on the story you are trying to tell.  Take [Stargate SG-1](http://stargate.mgm.com/view/series/1/) for example, they traveled the galaxy (and eventually other galaxies) through a stable wormhole connected by two stargates.  In this world, wormholes were made possible by the technology of an advanced species.

What type of story are you trying to tell with the wormhole?  Is it the center point of the story, or is it there facilitate telling a different story?

Comment: Hi, FiveHead, welcome to Worldbuilding SE. Good to see you contributing. We prefer detailed responses with discussion and information focused on the question. Your answer is closer to a comment than a full answer. The question is how close to the solar system can a wormhole be built. If you have any information about wormholes that will help the OP, please contribute it. Thanks.

Comment: @a4android my first instinct was to leave a comment, but I didn't have enough reputation.  Thanks for info, once I hit 50 rep I'll know better.

Comment: Don't worry. We all start by making mistakes. I certainly did, the thing to do is learn better and I'm sure you will.

Comment: Is it a mistake if the system doesn't allow you to do it?  I can't comment because I don't have the required reputation, so I decided to answer so I could get some reputation, or at least hope to get some. :)  Given the setup of the system answers are encouraged over comments, at least in the beginning.  Maybe this should go the meta portion...

Comment: Mistake was too strong a word. I made other errors on my first outing. Certainly answers & questions are privileged over comments. I'm less than pleased by this feature too. Yes it should be raised in meta.